# How can I view the STRUCTURE of an indexed table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, non-clustered-index

I have a general idea of what an indexed table looks like: first columns are indexed fields, last column is row id from the indexed table. But is there any way for me to actually view what a non-clustered indexed table looks like in SQL Server?

Comment: You can use SQL Server Internals Viewer on Codeplex (available for 2008 and 2008 R2 but not 2012) but also best reading something like the SQL Server internals book to make sense of what it shows.

Comment: Clustered and non-clustered indexes don't have a very different structure internally. They are almost exactly identical on-disk and regarding behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy

It explains the internal structure of B-tree indexes in general.